# Setting pointers in values.yaml

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

```
prometheus:
  target2: &target2 "x.x.x.x:31080"
```

This is a part of the values.yaml in my charts. I want to be able to set it through helm --set. Something like this:

```
helm upgrade grap . --set prometheus.target2="&target2 \"1.1.1.1:31080\""
```

But, the above is not working. Please let me know how it can be possible.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is not going to work since `--set` treats your parameter as string and not as anchor. I was wondering if this would work with `--values` but my test was not successful and the anchor was not propagated.

Here is the example where I tried to use `--values` :

```
#templates/file.yaml 
A: {{ .Values.asd }} 
B: {{ .Values.qwe }}

values.yaml 
asd: &anch 123 
qwe: *anch
```

The values before patch:

```
helm template .

Source: asdasd/templates/file.yaml 
A: 123 
B: 123
```

Here we place the patch using `--values`:

```
helm template . --values <(cat << EOF 
asd: &anch 789
EOF 
)
```

And the result of it:

```
--- 
#Source: asdasd/templates/file.yaml 
A: 789 
B: 123
```

As you can see after the patch and decoding the anchor is being lost.

Worth to mention here is that Helm and K8s very often read, modify and rewrite yaml, so after decoding the anchors will be lost. Helm docs describes this [here](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/yaml_techniques/).

Comment: I think a YAML anchor is specific to the file it's in, but in Helm you can have multiple YAML files and `--set` options are separate again.